# angularjs routing - not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I tried the code in visual studio as well as sublime text , there were no errors shown in the developer tools but when i try to inject any other html page for ex home.html it didnot update the page. here is the code i have made a reference. the address bar is like this:  http://localhost:63928/Index.html#!#%2Fhome while on the online tutorial i am learning only includes the /#home bar

here is index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="Demo">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <link href="Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/Script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="font-family: Arial">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="header">
                <h1>
                    WebSite Header
                </h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="leftmenu">
                <a href="#/home">Home</a>
                <a href="#/courses">Courses</a>
                <a href="#/students">Students</a>
            </td>
            <td class="maincontent">
                <ng-view></ng-view>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="footer">
                <b>Website Footer</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**my styles.css**

```
.header {
    width: 800px;
    height: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #BDBDBD;
}

.footer {
    background-color: #BDBDBD;
    text-align: center;
}

.leftmenu {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
    width: 150px;
}

.maincontent {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    width: 650px;
}

a {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px
}
```

**Script.js**

```
/// <reference path="angular.min.js" />

var app = angular
    .module("Demo", ["ngRoute"])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when("/home", {
                templateUrl: "Templates/home.html",
                controller: "homeController"
            })
            .when("/courses", {
                templateUrl: "Templates/courses.html",
                controller: "coursesController"
            })
            .when("/students", {
                templateUrl: "Templates/students.html",
                controller: "studentsController"
            })
    })
    .controller("homeController", function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Home Page";
    })
    .controller("coursesController", function ($scope) {
        $scope.courses = ["C#", "VB.NET", "ASP.NET", "SQL Server"];
    })
    .controller("studentsController", function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.students = ["Chiku", "Veeru", "ASHA", "SAchin"];
    })
```

and the home.html 
includes:

```
<h1>{{message}}</h1>


courses.html :


<h1>Courses we offer</h1>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="course in courses">
        {{course}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

students.html

```
<h1>List of Students</h1>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="student in students">
        {{student}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

if someone can findout any errors would be helpful to me
thanks.

Comment: What is the version of angular js that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

There are no changes i did, just check if your angular angular-route versions match.

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.10/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.js"></script>
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/OQe9XZx7fUbwb7DVhEhE?p=preview)**

Comment: i did'nt get you. my angular version and angular route version are different or what?